# Sharing lang files between modules in Laravel modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-modules

Is it possible to share lang files between two modules in nWidart/laravel-modules? I have a job that uses langs from module 1. Now I want to dispatch this job through module2 (and 2nd app_domain). I get an error.

> No hint path defined for [module1].

Is there any option to make both modules see the langs from module 1? I tried copy lang files to module 2.

Comment: Can you show how you called Lang? with namespace also ?

Comment: I solved this problem: I moved lang file from the Module to a level up to be globally visible by other Modules. And now it's ok.